# Problems when making a longtable table

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable

I am currently facing an issue with the longtable environment in LaTeX (using Overleaf). Specifically, I am getting the following error message: "Misplaced \noalign" when trying to compile my document.

I have a table that spans multiple pages using the longtable package. After some troubleshooting, I discovered that the error disappears when I remove the \hline commands within the table. However, this leads to the loss of the horizontal lines separating the table rows. Also getting rid of the \centering command seems to do the trick.

In addition to this error, I am also facing another problem with the table layout. The table extends beyond the bottom of the page, with the last entry positioned as low as the page number. This results in an unappealing visual appearance.

I have tried placing the \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule commands at the beginning and end of the longtable environment, but it did not resolve the issue. I now removed the rule commands entirely, which also did not really change anything.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or solutions to overcome these problems with the longtable environment. I want to ensure that the table retains the horizontal lines while fitting neatly within the page boundaries.

I created a test Latex Project and inserted the problematic code below. It still has the same behaviour. One of the column headers is blacked out, while the columns contents are split to the next page. See the below pictures for reference.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, colortbl}

\title{test}
\author{xyz}
\date{May 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{longtable}{p{7cm}p{7cm}}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \label{tab:Lorem_ipsum}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor[gray]{0.8}
        \toprule
            \textbf{Lorem ipsum} & \textbf{Lorem ipsum} \\ [0.5ex]
            \hline
        \midrule
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            \end{itemize}
            & 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            \end{itemize}
            \\ 
            \hline
        \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2 - note the text going below the page edge]

Comment: it doesn't make any sense to show code that doesn't issue your error. Make a small but complete example that demonstrates your problem. (The \hline is probably at the wrong place in the code).

Comment: I now editted the code to reflect the current status. The error still is not present, however what the table now does is that it splits itself up and does not span correctly. I can also post a picture of it if that would help

Comment: Your code is fine as long as ```longtable``` , ```booktabs```, and ```color``` packages are used. There must be some package clash. If you share ```preamble```, that would help. -Cheers

Comment: No, pictures do not help. If you want us to debug your code, you must show the faulty code. And you must show it in a way that we can reproduce the error. So something that starts with \documentclass and stops with \end{document}. With code it would take me a few minutes to correct your code.

Comment: I added the preamble with all the used packages. Have a look, sorry for the german.

Comment: Note that your example is not self contained (we do not have access to the files you include) and the example contains a lot of stuff that are not related to tables.

Comment: Well, I am no Overleaf/Latex pro. This is the template we got from the university, I added the longtable package as well as color and colortbl to make my tables stand out more.

I pasted in the entire preamble as I am not sure what is relevant to the troubleshooting and whats not.

Comment: You have a longtable that errors, so take that longtable and move it into testfile and surround it with \begin{document} and \end{document} . Add `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{longtable, booktabs, colortbl}` as preamble and nothing else and then compile. If it errors too you have a minimal example that you can show.

Comment: I now created a sample project and pasted the table in as you asked. It still looks the same, see the example code and pictures above.

Comment: It doesn't error, so don't fit your problem description. But apart from this: longtable can't break inside the list, only between rows.

Comment: I said in the description that I was able to fix the error by removing \centering and \hline. Okay, so what I need to do is to make the itemize into multiple rows?

Comment: your example _still_ is not an example of your problem.  Why can you not fix your question? but if you use `\centering` in any tabular-like code you may need to end the row with `\tabularnewline` rather than `\\ `